# How can I insert value in array inside object field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How can I insert an value in "total" array where pid = "123"

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("625bc1983016ed5208bbdf90"),
        "NAME" : "XYZ",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "pid" : "123",
                        "total" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "pid" : "456",
                        "total" : [ ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: can you exactly specify where you want to add buyers columns? inside total (array) or just a separate column like pid and total?

Comment: Sorry basically in total array.

Comment: can you specify what kind of output you want? inside total array an object or just a value? it will be better if you give a expected sample.

Comment: It will be objects eg.
`
total = [{id: 1}, {id : 2}]
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is:

```
db.collection.update({
  data: {
    $elemMatch: {
      pid: "123"
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "data.$.buyers": "some name"
  }
})
```

$elemMatch allows you to match more than one component within the same array element and then you can use `$set` to update the specific element.

You can run it here to check the same query https://mongoplayground.net/p/lveZw-8wkZ0

You can also have a look at documentation of `$elemMatch` in this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

Let me know if you face any issue.